# Including DLL in a MSI installer

Tags: dll, installation, windows-installer

Am on work experience placement and my boss is having trouble with this, Was hoping someone could help (And make me look clever :P). Have spent the last couple hours looking through stuff, without getting anywhere... much.

Basically: We have a program which currently requires the "2010 c++ redistributable" to run. The latest version of this program (.msi installer) includes the .dlls required to run the program, however the .dlls are not registered after running the installer. The program will not run (Until you install the "2010 c++ redistributable").

I think the problem could be something to do with administrator privileges. Not really sure. Any point in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redistribute these DLLs either by using [Merge Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235290(v=vs.100).aspx) - so instead of just packaging the DLLs themselves, you package the installer in side your own installer; or by including the redist exe in your installer, unpacking it to a temporary folder and then launching it.

You can download the redist installer for VS2010 [from Microsoft here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555) (x86 version).

There is a [related SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1190017/2065121) that describes the pros and cons of these alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Roger, Looking through that now.