# What is the best way to install VC++ redistributables via a group policy?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, wix, bootstrapper

This ought to be simple, but seems to be anything but.

I wish to create an installer that can be used by those using group policies to install products.  I do not know then if this must be an MSI, or an EXE.  Can an EXE install be installed via a group policy?  I chatted with another Wix novice who seemed to think it was a bad idea to have an install that was a plain MSI file.

My product uses the Visual C++ 2010 redistributables.  I do not wish to use merge modules.  Both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190017/should-i-use-vcredist-exe-or-the-msms-to-install-the-visual-c-runtime-library) and [this](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/MSVC-problem-on-Vista-no-SP-td6288551.html) link give some of the disadvantages of using them.  I object to 1) installing things that the user has not consented to, and 2) not having a control panel uninstall item with a version number that users can inspect and see if they have the latest version of.  Thus, I am not interested in responses consisting of people lecturing me on why I ought to use merge modules.  If what I am asking for is truly IMPOSSIBLE without merge modules, then please explain why.

I do not know if it is necessary to use a bootstrapper to kick off an EXE install.  I gather that it is, but it seems bizarre for me, for an MSI with such involved tables and descriptions, not to be able to kick of a mere EXE, ON THE CONDITION that the redistributable is not installed already.

If it is necessary to use a bootstrapper, I would like to know if anyone can find a complete example, with both bootstrapper and Wix code, for an example of a product install; ideally, together with the command lines necessary to compile them, for such a common case as installing a VC++ 2010 (or possibly 2012) program, together with its redistributable - with the latter being installed as the EXE.

I have found this to be straight-forward and easy to do in Inno Setup Pascal - except for the Group Policy part.  I have found anything but COMPLETE examples and/or straightforward explanations to accomplish this using a Microsoft installer.  No matter what Microsoft says, I would consider such an installer to be best practices.  My code is not managed, and I would like to support XP.  Thus, a bootstrapper that requires some .net to already be installed would only add another unsolved layer of complexity to the problem.  One that statically links to a .net library might not be too bad, if it did not create very much overhead.  My MSI install seems to work pretty well.  I did not realize that installing a vcredist_x86.exe would be a problem with such an elusive solution.  I do not have Visual Studio.  I am using the Qt framework, and have Visual Studio installed only to compile my application.  If you have a bootstrapper solution, please specify which bootstrapper you are using.  Ideally, the same idea could be extended to more than one prerequisite, and the same coding pattern could be used.  If there were a way to use a merge module or additional MSI so that the redistributable would have its own control panel entry, that could be acceptable.

Brownie points for suggesting a mailing list, forum or well-populated chat channel to talk about Wix that does not require one to receive a lot of unnecessary mailing list traffic.

Comment: Windows Installer, which actually "runs" MSI, can run dll's (and exe's) just fine, but if they try to start another install they will run into a "only one install at a time" wall.

Comment: That sounds like it includes vcredist_x86.exe.  Is that indeed the case, or does that apply only to MSI's?

Comment: From George Vella's comment below, vcredist_x86.exe expands into an MSI, so this would include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group Policies by default don't allow EXEs to be installed.  I did read about some admins that repackage EXEs into MSIs to deploy them via GPO but that is rather hacky.  There is also the possibility to script the deployment - GPOs support script execution, machine or user level.

You can't embed an MSI within another MSI either because only one installation can execute at any time (Windows Installer design).

I don't know how you will be providing your product to your customers but vcredist_x86.exe (I am trying this with the v100 version) uncompresses into the root folder and generates an msi and a cab (vc_red.msi and vc_red.cab) among other files.  If you provide these to your customers they can add them to the same GPO used to deploy your product.

Comment: I'm not particular about how to provide it.  That would be a fallback, but it would I'd prefer to kick off the install automatically, only if it is needed.  As above, I have an MSI that seems to do the job except for the prerequisite already, with just a little tweaking left to do.

Comment: There is another option.  You could package the runtime DLLs and mainfest files into your MSI and install them in your product's installation folder.  Updates to the runtime provided via windows update won't update your DLLs, but it could be done and works nicely too.

Comment: As in my question, that doesn't get me a control panel uninstall entry users can inspect and install updates for if needed.

Comment: Then your options are really limited.  The Software Installation section of GPO accepts only MSIs and you can't invoke another installation from your product's MSI because windows installer will surely complain (an installation is already running error) since only one program can be installed at a time.  If you want to keep everything clean, then in your manual, instruct the admin to add vc_red.msi to the GPO that s/he will use to deploy your program.

Comment: If that is the case, I'm not sure if I can redistribute the extracted MSI from the vcredist_86.exe msi legally.  I have seen how people use merge modules to create an MSI just for the redistributable.  This brings up the question: can one MSI create two control panel uninstall entries?

Comment: I'm choosing yours as the best answer; although I'm not entirely sure that there's not a better answer.  I just don't know much about group policy installs.